# How to sum periods between dates in linq c# till a specific period

Tags: c#, linq, date, sum

## I have a datatable that contains three columns, I need to check when each employee ID reached two or will reach two years by subtracting `Date1` from `Date2` and sum the difference by a LINQ query.

If `Date2` value is null that means `ID` is still working till now.

```
   ID                    Date1                                 Date2
>  100              10/01/2016                               09/01/2017               
>  100              20/09/2017                               25/05/2019  
>  101              05/07/2018
```

**I need output like below:**

```
   ID                two_years
> 100                    19/09/2018   
> 101                    04/07/2020
```

Comment: so where is the code with the subtraction? and where is your problem description of what exactly did not work when you tried to subtract

Comment: You can subtract one `DateTime` from another and the result is a `TimeSpan` which represents a duration of time. If that duration is two years or more then the two dates are two years or more apart. I'm not sure what the sum part is about - sum of what? But that's okay. If you solve the first part - finding the employees - then the second part, whatever it is, will be a little bit easier.

Comment: Why is `04/07/2019` two years after `05/07/2018`? What code have you tried? How do you define two years?

Comment: Sorry it should be 04/07/2020

Comment: I need to sum durations together for each ID, if the total is more than two years check in which date two years are completed, for example in first row ID 100 completed one year and in second completed about one year and four months, so total is more than two years and find in which date two years are completed and that was in 19/09/2018

Comment: How do you define two years _exactly_?

Answer (score 0):

Using my `Scan` extension which is based on the APL Scan operator (like `Aggregate`, only it returns the intermediate results):

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // TRes seedFn(T FirstValue)
    // TRes combineFn(TRes PrevResult, T CurValue)
    public static IEnumerable<TRes> Scan<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TRes> seedFn, Func<TRes, T, TRes> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prev = seedFn(srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prev;
                    prev = combineFn(prev, srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prev;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then assuming by two years, you mean 2 * 365 days, and assuming you count the beginning and ending dates of each period as part of the total, this LINQ will find the answer:

```
var ans = src.Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Date1, s.Date2, Diff = (s.Date2.HasValue ? s.Date2.Value-s.Date1 : DateTime.Now.Date-s.Date1).TotalDays+1 })
             .GroupBy(s => s.ID)
             .Select(sg => new { ID = sg.Key, sg = sg.Scan(s => new { s.Date1, s.Date2, s.Diff, DiffAccum = s.Diff }, (res, s) => new { s.Date1, s.Date2, s.Diff, DiffAccum = res.DiffAccum + s.Diff }) })
             .Select(IDsg => new { IDsg.ID, two_year_base = IDsg.sg.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DiffAccum > twoYears) ?? IDsg.sg.Last() })
             .Select(s => new { s.ID, two_years = s.two_year_base.Date1.AddDays(twoYears-(s.two_year_base.DiffAccum - s.two_year_base.Diff)).Date });
```

If your original data is not sorted in `Date1` order, or `ID`+`Date1` order, you will need to add `OrderBy` to sort by `Date1`.

Explanation:
First we compute the days worked(?) represented by each row, using today if we don't have an ending `Date2`. Then group by ID and work on each group. For each ID, we compute the running sum of days worked. Next find the `Date1` that proceeds the two year mark using the running sum (`DiffAccum`) and compute the two year date from `Date1` and the remaining time needed in that period.

If it is possible a particular ID could have a lot of periods, you could use another variation of `Scan`, `ScanUntil` which short circuits evaluation based on a predicate.